# Auto click on a div when I reach at the bottom of the page

Tags: click

I want to auto click a div when I reach to the bottom of the page. How can I do this?
I got this piece of code but I cannot get it to work when I reach the bottom of the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

$('#some-id').trigger('click');
});

Any help how to do this?
Auto click on a div when I reach at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you would like to auto click a div instead of initiating an action.

Comment: I have a div for "View More" and when I click on it, the older posts load but I want it load automatically when a user is on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could detect if the user is at the bottom of the page and initiate a jquery function (same as on the div) to load the new content.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        alert("bottom!");
    }
  });
});
```

[Example](https://tinker.io/4dc1a/1)

Comment: Actually, I want to auto click the span.ow_button when anyone is at the bottom of the page, to load the new posts. So, I used the following code

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
   $('span.ow_button').trigger('click');
  }
 });
});